# Google now crashes on sony xperia m after update to JB 4.3

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, google-now, sony-xperia

I have got Sony Xperia M (C1904) it was first with JB 4.1 update. I got very soon update to JB 4.2.2 and google now crash when keep long touch on home button. I got another update to JB 4.3 same problem continued but now after some usage of phone.

Anyone who know how to get rid of this?

I want Google Now launches after long touch of home button or swipe home button as it was working on JB 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all the updates to Google Search in the Google Play store.  Restart, and reinstall.